# R replace elements

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
fruits_v <- c(150, -50, 20, -100, 200)
```

and i must create an other vector `profit_fruits` that will contain `TRUE` for every positive number in `fruits_v` and `FALSE` for every negative. (Without using for loop)

Can anybody help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
profit_fruits <- fruits_v > 0
```

R will internally vectorize the inequality check, and return a vector whose length is the same as `fruits_v`, with true/false for each comparison.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sign`

```
sign(fruits_v) >= 0
```